# What is SSTP vpn server and how can I run one?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, vpn

I've read a couple of L2TP and PPTP tutorials on the net and there are just dozens of "running PPTP/L2TP on Linux" guides available out there and I successfully made packages like open-swan or pptpd to work.

Now, I've heard that SSTP protocol is also available for creating a VPN. My questions are:

1. What is this protocol? Is it really safer than L2TP?
2. Is it a Windows-specific protocol? (There are no guides available on Google for running such VPN servers on Linux. - as far as I searched)
3. **And the most important question:** how can I run such server on my Cent-OS box?

By SSTP I don't mean packages like Open-VPN, I mean the same thing that windows can connect to it without any further clients. just like PPTP and L2TP.

Any resource for my reading would be also really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's a tunneling protocol over ssl, as far as security goes: I'll leave that answer to someone else as I'm not that into it
2. No, you can run a server on Windows, Mac and Linux with http://www.softether.org/
3. Go check the soft ether website